# How to filter a list based on a substring in each element?

Tags: python

I have an inconsistent list of strings that contain dates in different formats. I need to determine the dates in each list.

My list/array looks like:

```py
dates_list = []
my_array = [
'5364345354_01.05.2019.pdf',
'5364344354_ 01.05.2019.pdf',
'5345453454 - 21.06.2019.pdf',
'4675535643 - 19 June 2019.docx',
'57467874 25.06.18.pdf',
'6565653635_20 March 2019.txt',
'252252452_31.1.2019.txt'
]
```

I've tried a for loop and tried splitting the string however each string has different delimiters before the date. So what's a plausible way to find the date from each string in this inconsistent list. The only help looking at the list is that the date are all positioned at the end of each string

Comment: Are these *all* the possible variants of strings you have to parse?

Comment: Yes I have checked my list and filter it down to those 7@MisterMiyagi

Comment: `25.06.18` is 25 June 2018, right?

Comment: Try using `regex`

Comment: Yes @wjandrea  .

Comment: Regex won't work @vaku

Comment: Why wont regex work?

Comment: Is it always "numbers, deliminators, date, filetype?" If so, just find the first number after the first non-number and extract until the last  '.'

Answer (score 0):

well it is not the best way to do it, but it may solve your problem, you can adapt it more :

```
dates_list = []
my_array = [
'5364345354_01.05.2019.pdf',
'5364344354_ 01.05.2019.pdf',
'5345453454 - 21.06.2019.pdf',
'4675535643 - 19 June 2019.docx',
'57467874 25.06.18.pdf',
'6565653635_20 March 2019.txt',
'252252452_31.1.2019.txt'
]

import os 

for i in my_array : 
  for j in i : 
    if j >= '0' and j <= '9' : 
      i = i.replace(j,"",1)
    else:
      break 
  print(os.path.splitext(i)[0].replace("_","").replace("-",""))
```

output :

```
01.05.2019
01.05.2019
21.06.2019
19 June 2019
25.06.18
20 March 2019
31.1.2019
```

Comment: Will it work with a string like “039383930 01_04_19”?

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you want to do with the dates or if you want them in some sort of consistent format however all your question states is you want to extract the date from the file name. you can do this with regex based on your samples which you say are the only 7 formats you have.

```
my_array = [
'5364345354_01.05.2019.pdf',
'5364344354_ 01.05.2019.pdf',
'5345453454 - 21.06.2019.pdf',
'4675535643 - 19 June 2019.docx',
'57467874 25.06.18.pdf',
'6565653635_20 March 2019.txt',
'252252452_31.1.2019.txt'
]

import re
for filename in my_array:
    date = re.search(r'(\d{1,2}([.\s])(?:\d{1,2}|\w+)\2\d{2,4})', filename).group()
    print(f"The date '{date}' was extracted from the file name '{filename}'")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The date '01.05.2019' was extracted from the file name '5364345354_01.05.2019.pdf'
The date '01.05.2019' was extracted from the file name '5364344354_ 01.05.2019.pdf'
The date '21.06.2019' was extracted from the file name '5345453454 - 21.06.2019.pdf'
The date '19 June 2019' was extracted from the file name '4675535643 - 19 June 2019.docx'
The date '25.06.18' was extracted from the file name '57467874 25.06.18.pdf'
The date '20 March 2019' was extracted from the file name '6565653635_20 March 2019.txt'
The date '31.1.2019' was extracted from the file name '252252452_31.1.2019.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module is helpful when working with dates and date formats and may help to convert your various format dates to a single format.

Extra characters, like the number in front of the dates, still need to be stripped manually. Other answers already pointed out several ways to do it, here I propose my own which does not require regex. I'm going to assume that the patterns are the one shown in your example, if there are other patters they need to be included in the code.

Once the numbers at the beginning of the strings and the file extension are discarded, `datetime.strptime()` is used to read the date and create a `datetime` object.
Then `datetime.strftime()` is used to get back a string representing the date with a given, unique format.

```
import datetime

my_array = [
'5364345354_01.05.2019.pdf',
'5364344354_ 01.05.2019.pdf',
'5345453454 - 21.06.2019.pdf',
'4675535643 - 19 June 2019.docx',
'57467874 25.06.18.pdf',
'6565653635_20 March 2019.txt',
'252252452_31.1.2019.txt'
]

def multiformat(string, format_list, format_res):
    delim = None
    if '_' in string:
        delim = '_'
    elif '-' in string:
        delim = '-'
    else:
        delim = ' '

    strdate = string.split(delim)[1].strip().split('.')[:-1]
    txtdate = ' '.join(strdate)

    print(txtdate)
    date = None
    for frm in format_list:
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(txtdate, frm)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return date.strftime(format_res)

format_dates = ['%d %m %Y', '%d %m %y', '%d %B %Y']
dates_list = list(map(lambda x : multiformat(x, format_dates, '%d-%m-%Y'), my_array))
print(dates_list)
```

This prints:

```
['01-05-2019', '01-05-2019', '21-06-2019', '19-06-2019', '25-06-2018', '20-03-2019', '31-01-2019']
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved with regex. The pattern I'm using here works in this case, but it's not pretty.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}(\.| )\w+\1\d{2,4}')

for f in my_array:
    print(regex.search(f).group())
```

Output:

```
01.05.2019
01.05.2019
21.06.2019
19 June 2019
25.06.18
20 March 2019
31.1.2019
```

Broken down:

- `\d{1,2}` - One or two digits
- `(\.| )` ... `\1` - A dot or a space, then the same again
- `\w+` - One or more letters, digits, or underscores
- `\d{2,4}` - Two or four digits

Answer (score -1):

you could try this, a little hacky but you do have some variations in your date formats:)

```
import re
mons = {'January':'01','February':'02','March':'03','April':'04','May':'05','June':'06','July':'07','August':'08','September':'09','October':'10','November':'11','December':'12'}

unformatted = [re.sub('\d{5,}|\s-\s|_|\s','',d.rsplit('.',1)[0]).replace('.','-') for d in my_array]
```

output:

```
['01-05-2019', '01-05-2019', '21-06-2019', '19June2019', '25-06-18', '20March2019', '31-1-2019']

for i,d in enumerate(unformatted):
    if any(c.isalpha() for c in d):
        key = re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',d).group()
        unformatted[i] = d.replace(key,'-'+mons[key]+'-')
    if len(d.split('-')[-1])==2:
        yr = d.split('-')[-1]
        unformatted[i] = d[:-2]+'20'+yr

#was having issues getting this one to work in the same loop..but:
for i,d in enumerate(unformatted):
    if len(d.split('-')[1])==1:
        mnth = d.split('-')[1]
        unformatted[i] = d[:3]+'0'+mnth+d[-5:]
```

output:

```
['01-05-2019', '01-05-2019', '21-06-2019', '19-06-2019', '25-06-2018', '20-03-2019', '31-01-2019']
```

this not only extracts the date for each entry, but puts them into the same format so you can use them in pandas, or whatever you need to do with them afterwards

if the provided example contains all variations of the dates, this should work, if not you could make some minor adaptations and should be able to get it to work